# Can pg_dump be broken into batches for large DBs?

Tags: postgresql, export, pg-dump

I have a fairly huge DB and `pg_dump` croaks on me when I try to export it to a single file. Is there a way to do it in batches, whereby each batch would cover a segment of tables and export the schema/data in its own file rather than all in one file?

Comment: You mean, something like the `--table` option?

Comment: Not really, I would prefer if the utility itself determined how to break down the export rather than myself having to specify tables. I don't want to do that because there are RI dependencies

Comment: It would be possible to pipe the dump output into [split](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html), but then you would not have independent files.

Comment: You could export one schema at a time using `-n`, but that would lose dependencies across schemas.  And very easily could "croak" anyway at the individual schema.  Problems are usually best addressed head on.  Why is it croaking?